# Overlay popover on top of an image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, popover

I'm trying to create a picture link that includes a question mark glyph that a user can click on to reveal a popover with instructions.

Right now, the question mark glyph appears at the bottom, but ideally I would like that to be right next to the title of the link "My Information".

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
a.picture {
  margin: 20px 0;
  position: relative; 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: top;
}

a.picture > h3 {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

a.picture > h3 span {
   display:block;
   color: white; 
   font-weight: bold;  
   background: $blue;
   padding: 10px; 
}

    <a ng-if="::(options.link_template == 'Picture')" ng-href="{{::data.href}}" class="picture {{::options.class_name}}" target="{{::data.target}}" >
        <h3><span>{{::options.title}}</span></h3> 
      <img src="{{::options.picture}}" height="100%" width="100%"/>
        <div><a tabindex="0" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-trigger="focus" title="My Information" data-content="This is what this link will display"/></div>      
    </a>
```

What do I have to do in the css in order for the popover glyph to be next to the title?  I tried putting the glyphicon class next to the title, but having a link within a link doesn't seem to work well.

Thanks.

Comment: Would the upper right corner be satisfactory? You could [position it absolutely](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning#Absolute_positioning), relative to `a.picture`.

Answer (score 0):

Here the code you need :) Use flexbox

**Method used:** use a container div for the title and help mark, set to top using position absolute and centering it with flex.

> Flexbox guide https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.image {
  position:relative;
  width:200px;
  height:250px;
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}

.header {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  background:rgba(255,255,255, .5);
  color:#000;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
}

span {
  margin:0 5px;
}

.help {
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  background:red;
  /** or use margin 0 5px 0 auto to align right **/
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="header">
    <span>My info</span>
    <div class="help"></div>
  </div>
  <img src="http://maximumwallhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/fonds-ecran-paysage-de-reve-161-660x330.jpg">
</div>
```